# Is it possible to call a web page LOAD event from JQuery OnClient Click event?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have created a dialog box that calls a user Control for creating a grid and populating it respectively. but this user control is used earlier, so when I am showing the dialog box, it is showing me the same grid. So, in order to call the user control again, i want its load event to get fired again. Is it possible to do this. Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ReviewGroupGrid" Src="UserControls/ReviewGroupGrid.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ReviewGroupGrids" Src="UserControls/ReviewGroupGrid.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="OCM.Phoenix.WebToolsFramework.Server.Modules.DataSteward.WebExtensions" Namespace="OCM.Phoenix.WebToolsFramework.Server.Modules.DataSteward.WebExtensions" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="DataStewardContent">

<cc1:Button ID="btnMerge" runat="server" Text="Merge &amp; Edit" OnClick="btnMerge_Click"
                            OnClientClick="javascript:return reviewGroupForm.getSelectedRowsForMerge()" />
<div class="modal-dialog" id="updateClaimConfirmPopUp" style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="popUpHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close closeClaimPopUp">
                <span>&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="confirmData">
            <div id="random"></div>
            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <uc:ReviewGroupGrids ID="reviewGroupCtrls" runat="Server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="claimMerge" CssClass="buttonClassClaim btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Accept" OnClick="btnMerge_Click"/>
            <button type="button" id="btnClosePopUp" class="buttonClassClaim btn btn-primary closeClaimPopUp">
                Discard</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**jQuery**

```
getSelectedRowsForMerge: function () {
                               var entityType = $("input[id*='hdnEntityType']").val();
                                if (entityType === "19") {
                                $('#popUpHeader').find('h4').remove();
                                $('#random').find('h4').remove();
                                $('#popUpHeader').append('  <h4 class="modal-title" >  ' + 'Need Your' + ' Attention!</h4>');
                                $('#random').append('<h4><b> ' + 'The Claims that you are merging are associated with different patients, merging the claims will result in explicit merging of the associated Patients as well, Please review the patient(s) details shown below before merging the claim' + '</b></h4>');
                                //$('#confirmData').append('<div class="table-responsive"').append(' <uc:ReviewGroupGrid ID="reviewGroupCtrl" runat="Server" />').append('</div>');
                                $("#updateClaimConfirmPopUp").dialog({
                                    autoOpen: true,
                                    width: 1600,
                                    resizable: false,
                                    draggable: true,
                                    modal: true,
                                    show: { effect: 'blind' }
                                });
                            }
},
```

When my dialog box is getting created, it is creating the user control but this user control is already populated. I want to call its load event so that the user control processes again. Can i do this via click event when opening the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the btnMerge to refresh the div everytime its shown. If so then you need to get the data from server via ajax call in your getSelectedRowsForMerge which can update the data shown in your ReviewGroupGrids control. In the success handler of this promise, set the popup to be shown and not immediately. This will refresh everything in the div and not require any server side load event

Snippet as follows, please add real code

```
getSelectedRowsForMerge: function () {
// various cleanups as present
$.ajax(...)
    .success( function() {
            //show the div
             $("#updateClaimConfirmPopUp").dialog({  ....  } );
           })
```